# How could I untar all .tar files in a directory to folders based on filename of each .tar?

Tags: tar

I could do this for `.zip` files in the folder using the command below:

```
for f in "!"; do unzip -d "${f%*.zip}" "$f"; done
```

The above command extracts all `.zip` files in a given folder to subfolders, having content and name of respective `.zip` files.

But I couldn't find a command that would do the same for `.tar` files. Please help.

Btw, I am trying to do this on a remote server using WinSCP/putty. So, I cannot use a GUI software. I need a command, thus the question.

Comment: What's preventing you from doing the same thing for tars?

Comment: that's first thing I tried, didn't get it to working.

Here are the command I used that didn't work:

for f in "!"; do tar xvf -d "${f%*.tar}" "$f"; done

for f in "!"; do tar xvf -C "${f%*.tar}" "$f"; done

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of fiddling I came up with `for f in $(find -maxdepth 1 | grep .tar); do mkdir ${f%.tar}; tar -xaf $f -C ${f%.tar} ; done` appears to work, so long as the file name does not contain any spaces. I assume you wanted the directory from `foo.tar` to be named `foo` (no file extension). If you want the directory to be named `foo.tar` (with file extension) then try using `for f in $(find -maxdepth 1 | grep .tar); do mkdir $f ; tar -xaf $f -C $f ; done`.
IIRC, the remote access client Cyberduck can handle compressed files in a GUI - so you can try that if you're fine with a GUI solution.